# How do I get the enhanced++ dependencies of CoreNLP using the Stanza python wrapper in google colab?

Tags: stanford-nlp

[Stanza with Basic Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dkai.png)

I need to get the enhanced++ dependencies instead of the above basic dependencies.
I have used the code from here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/depparse.html

Answer (score 0):

The Stanza depparse model only produces basic dependencies.  However, there is a universal converter using a pipe to a Java process from CoreNLP which may help:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/client_regex.html#universal-enhancements

If you have any issues using that, I suggest posting an issue on the stanza github